# Своя реализация Drag and Drop

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html5, jsfiddle

**Задание**: Реализовать собственный Drag and Drop

**Условия**:

- Не использовать каких либо библиотек, кроме JQuery
- Не использовать стандартную реализацию Drag and Drop в JQuery

**Проблема**:

Элемент при перетаскивании перекрывает собой событие контейнера `hover`, из за этого невозможно сделать проверку, находится ли курсор мыши над контейнером.

```js
var divBoxes = $('#boxes');
var divBoxLeft = divBoxes.find('.box-left');
var divBoxRight = divBoxes.find('.box-right');

var divOperations = $('#operations');
var buttonCreateItem = divOperations.find('.button-create-item');
var buttonClearLeftBox = divOperations.find('.button-clear-left-box');
var buttonClearRightBox = divOperations.find('.button-clear-right-box');

$(buttonCreateItem).click(function() {
  let newItem = $('<div class="item"></div>');

  let width = 50;
  let height = 50;

  var isPermittedDropped;

  function itemDrag(e) {
    newItem.addClass('dragged');
    newItem.css({
      position: 'absolute',
      top: e.clientY - height / 2,
      left: e.clientX - width / 2
    });

    $(divBoxRight).hover(
      function() {
        isPermittedDropped = true;
        $('hover-info').text("Hover");

      },
      function() {
        isPermittedDropped = false;
        $('hover-info').text("No hover");
      });
  }

  function itemDrop(e) {
    if (isPermittedDropped)
      divBoxRight.append($(divBoxLeft).find('.item.dragged'));

    $('html').off('mousemove', itemDrag);
    $(divBoxRight).off('mouseenter mouseleave');

    newItem.removeClass('dragged');
    newItem.css({
      position: 'static',
      top: '',
      left: ''
    });
  }

  newItem.mousedown(function() {
    $('html').on('mousemove', itemDrag);
  });
  newItem.mouseup(itemDrop);

  let red = Math.random() * 255;
  let green = Math.random() * 255;
  let blue = Math.random() * 255;
  let alpha = 0.25 + Math.random() * (1 - 0.25);

  newItem.css({
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(' + red + ', ' + green + ', ' + blue + ', ' + alpha + ')'
  });

  divBoxLeft.append(newItem);
});
$(buttonClearLeftBox).click(function() {
  divBoxLeft.empty();
});
$(buttonClearRightBox).click(function() {
  divBoxRight.empty();
});
```

```css
.container {
  max-width: 1300px;
  margin: 25px auto;
  text-align: center;
}

#boxes,
#operations {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  user-select: none;
}

#boxes [class^='box'] {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-grow: 1;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: flex-start;
  overflow-y: auto;
  max-width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: solid 3px #CCC;
  background-color: #FFF;
}

#boxes [class^='box'] .item {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: solid 1px #CCC;
}

#operations [class^='button'] {
  width: 250px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: solid 1px #CCC;
  background-color: aqua;
}

#operations [class^='button']:hover {
  border-width: 0px;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15)), #0FF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div id="boxes">
    <div class="box-left"></div>
    <div class="box-right"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="operations">
    <button class="button-create-item">Создать элемент</button>
    <button class="button-clear-left-box">Очистить левый контейнер</button>
    <button class="button-clear-right-box">Очистить правый контейнер</button>
  </div>
  <div class="hover-info">No hover</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Ответ**: Заменить проверку события `hover` на проверку координат мыши.

```js
var divBoxes = $('#boxes'),
  divBoxLeft = divBoxes.find('.box-left'),
  divBoxRight = divBoxes.find('.box-right');

var divOperations = $('#operations'),
  buttonCreateItem = divOperations.find('.button-create-item'),
  buttonClearLeftBox = divOperations.find('.button-clear-left-box'),
  buttonClearRightBox = divOperations.find('.button-clear-right-box');

var divBoxRightCoords = divBoxRight.offset(),
  divBoxRightBorderTop = divBoxRightCoords.top,
  divBoxRightBorderBottom = divBoxRightCoords.top + divBoxRight.height(),
  divBoxRightBorderLeft = divBoxRightCoords.left,
  divBoxRightBorderRight = divBoxRightCoords.left + divBoxRight.width();

$(buttonCreateItem).click(function() {
  let newItem = $('<div class="item"></div>');

  let width = 50,
    height = 50;

  function itemDrag(e) {
    newItem.addClass('dragged');
    newItem.css({
      position: 'absolute',
      top: e.clientY - height / 2,
      left: e.clientX - width / 2
    });
  }

  function itemDrop(e) {
    if (e.clientX >= divBoxRightBorderLeft && e.clientX <= divBoxRightBorderRight)
      if (e.clientY >= divBoxRightBorderTop && e.clientY <= divBoxRightBorderBottom)
        divBoxRight.append($(divBoxLeft).find('.item.dragged'));

    $('html').off('mousemove', itemDrag);

    newItem.removeClass('dragged');
    newItem.css({
      position: 'static',
      top: '',
      left: ''
    });
  }

  newItem.mousedown(function() {
    $('html').on('mousemove', itemDrag);
  });
  newItem.mouseup(itemDrop);

  let red = Math.random() * 255,
    green = Math.random() * 255,
    blue = Math.random() * 255,
    alpha = 0.25 + Math.random() * (1 - 0.25);

  newItem.css({
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(' + red + ', ' + green + ', ' + blue + ', ' + alpha + ')'
  });

  divBoxLeft.append(newItem);
});
$(buttonClearLeftBox).click(function() {
  divBoxLeft.empty();
});
$(buttonClearRightBox).click(function() {
  divBoxRight.empty();
});
```

```css
.container {
  max-width: 1300px;
  margin: 25px auto;
}

#boxes,
#operations {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  user-select: none;
}

#boxes [class^='box'] {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-grow: 1;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: flex-start;
  overflow-y: auto;
  max-width: 420px;
  height: 420px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: solid 3px #CCC;
  background-color: #FFF;
}

#boxes [class^='box'] .item {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: solid 1px #CCC;
}

#operations [class^='button'] {
  width: 250px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 10px;
  outline: none;
  border: solid 1px #CCC;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: aqua;
}

#operations [class^='button']:hover {
  border-width: 0px;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15)), #0FF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div id="boxes">
    <div class="box-left"></div>
    <div class="box-right"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="operations">
    <button class="button-create-item">Создать элемент</button>
    <button class="button-clear-left-box">Очистить левый контейнер</button>
    <button class="button-clear-right-box">Очистить правый контейнер</button>
  </div>
</div>
```